# Broadleaf Microservices Deployment Options

Tags: docker, broadleaf-commerce

I noticed that Broadleaf has a myriad of different services such as the 'Catalog Service' and 'Asset Service' in https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/MicroservicesTutorial. I would like to deploy each service in their own Docker container on Kubernetes, but have them all talk to the same Postgres database instance to simplify my AWS management. Is this possible or will I get table collisions across those services? How would I achieve that using the tutorial?